# Progressive Angular App With Server Side Rendering Not Building Index

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

Im building a progressive angular app that uses angular universal for server side rendering. Im having trouble getting the SSR to work. This app is hooked up to postgres and uses express/node on the backend. The exact issue is when running the server, I cannot load the app. I am getting an error that says it cannot find the index file but I am seeing the index file in the dist folder which is claims it cannot find.

The error I am getting

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "./dist"
    at Function.render (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:971:7)
    at angularRouter (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/app.js:21:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/app.js:63:10
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/app.js:53:3
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at SendStream.error (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:121:7)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/fashion-api/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:425:31)
```

My app.js file for the backend

```
require('zone.js/dist/zone-node'); require('reflect-metadata'); const compression = require('compression'); const express = require('express'); const ngUniversal = require('@nguniversal/express-engine'); const { provideModuleMap } = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader'); const { AppServerModuleFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist-server/main.bundle'); const path = require('path'); const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); const bodyParser = require("body-parser"); const logger = require('morgan'); // const url
= "https://www.rebargoapp.com"; const devUrl = "http://localhost:4200";


const index = require('./server/routes/index');


// view engine setup function angularRouter(req,res) {   res.render('index', {req,res}); }

const app = express();

app.engine('html', ngUniversal.ngExpressEngine({   boostrap: AppServerModuleFactory,   providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)   ] }));

require('dotenv').config();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); app.use(compression()); app.set('views', './dist'); // app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico'))); app.use(logger('dev')); app.use(bodyParser.json()); app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}, {limit: '50mb'})); app.use(cookieParser()); app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(function (req,res,next) {   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",  (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') ? devUrl : devUrl);   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, PATCH, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);   next(); });

app.use(function(req, res, next) {   if (process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    if(req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"] === "https"){
      return next();
    }
    return res.redirect('https://'+req.hostname+req.url);   }   return next(); });

app.use('/', angularRouter);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './dist')));

app.use('*', angularRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

I can see the index file in my dist folder when building. here is the command I run to build the application `"build:ssr": "ng build --prod --aot && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=none --aot && sw-precache --root=dist-server --config=precache-config.js",`

And here is my angular-cli.json file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "rebargo-app"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "manifest.json"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "test_app",
      "root": "src",
      "platform": "server",
      "outDir": "dist-server",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "manifest.json"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "main": "main.server.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Which builds both the client and server side apps using that command.

Can anyone figure out why I can render this application?

*** Update
I just wanted to show my folder structure so you can see index.html in dist[image]

Comment: Make sure it's not a relative path problem. var DIST_FOLDER = path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist'); app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER ')

Comment: I tried that and now I'm getting the relative path.  ``Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/workspace/example-api/dist"``

Comment: Is it because you used ejs as a view engine? Then it'll look for injex.ejs by default? Try using app.set('view engine', 'html'); or renaming index.hmlt to index.ejs

Answer (score 0):

You need to use html as the view engine, instead of ejs, since your expressengine is specified for 'html' and your index file is index.html

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```